Code to move specific columns of a row to another sheet when status is changed on that row
I'm new to coding and looking for some help. I have code to move an entire row in Google sheets when a status changes as follows:
 var editedRange = e.range;
var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
console.log(editedRow);

if (editedRange.getColumn() === statusColumn) {
var status = editedRange.getValue();
if (status === "Closed/Won") {
  var lastColumn = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);

  if (sourceData[0] != "") {
    sourceData.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    }

But I don't want to move the entire row and I am unsure how to modify the code to move only parts of the row, i.e. values from columns A,B,D,F,G,H, & M to another sheet to create a condensed version of the original table.
I have tried different combinations of changing edited row and last column and have also tried to create arrays but couldn't get that working.  Most answers I have found seem to only cover moving an entire row rather than specific columns within the row.

Move selected column of current to another sheet in same spreadsheet
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "SheetName" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "Closed/Won") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Log");
    const [a,b,,d,,f,g,h,,,,,m] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,13).getDisplayValues().flat();
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 7).setValues([[a,b,d,f,g,h,m]]);
    sh.deleteRows(e.range.rowStart)
  }
}

I don't know what the column number of status is so I chose 1.

Range.copyTo()


Thanks for answering, the column number of the status is 6 - I have tried to paste this in to Apps Script, but still no luck unfortunately as it hasn't moved anything over to the new sheet, do you have any other suggestions that may help?

Try it now.  Change the sheet name to your sheet name

All working now, thanks so much Cooper!
